# Storing data in the textbox for future use

Tags: vb.net

I want to store the number of cattle in a `TextBox` that will be updated frequently. Every time when the application executes the `TextBox` must display the most recent number stored in the textbox before the application was closed.
I would appreciate your input, thanks

Comment: One place to store data when your application exits is [My.Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx). Keep in mind that your `TextBox` contains text and not a number. You should probably keep the number in a numeric variable and just convert it to a string to display it in the `TextBox` when it is updated.

Comment: Thanks so much its working

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, you can easily bind a user setting to a control. The settings are automatically managed for you.  I was able to find this simple video which demonstrates the process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVCSRbfB8r4

This feature is supper easy to use and is extremely powerful in the sense that any class which is tagged with Serializable can be used in this utility; not just the basic types.

Good luck.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help. Would you mind flagging your question as answered?